# skipMiddlewares:true is safe/good in socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I'm reading the official documentation of socket.io about the [Connection state recovery](https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery), which says:

> ```
> const io = new Server(httpServer, {
>   connectionStateRecovery: {
>     // the backup duration of the sessions and the packets
>     maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000,
>     // whether to skip middlewares upon successful recovery
>     skipMiddlewares: true,
>   }
> });
> ```

If I'm right, here middlewares are functions that I set that will be invoked between other socket.io core functions, like after a new client connection, is it true?

And [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-options/#connectionstaterecovery):

> If the skipMiddlewares option is set to true, then the middlewares
> will be skipped when the connection is successfully recovered:
>
> ```
> function computeUserIdFromHeaders(headers) {
>   // to be implemented
> }
>
> // this middleware will be skipped if the connection is successfully recovered
> io.use(async (socket, next) => {
>   socket.data.userId = await computeUserIdFromHeaders(socket.handshake.headers);
>
>   next();
> });
>
> io.on("connection", (socket) => {
>   // the userId attribute will either come:
>   // - from the middleware above (first connection or failed recovery)
>   // - from the recevery mechanism
>   console.log("userId", socket.data.userId);
> });
> ```

So, while recovering the state, `skipMiddlewares:true` prevents middlewares from running but uses the backup packets data as-is, correct?

If so, is it a safe/good practice?